# Azure API Management: authorization with Oauth2 401 gives "Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid."

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-api-management

I have a few APIs (Logic Apps, Functions) that I want to expose through Azure API Management.
They work fine, so I decided to add OAuth2 autorization.

I followed step by step https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad:

- Register an application (backend-app) in Azure AD to represent the API.
- Register another application (client-app) in Azure AD to represent a client application that needs to call the API.
- In Azure AD, grant permissions to allow the client-app to call the backend-app.
- Configure the Developer Console to call the API using OAuth 2.0 user authorization.
- Add the validate-jwt policy to validate the OAuth token for every incoming request.
- Also use Postman to test

Everything works until the "validate-jwt" policy step.
When I add it, I get a "401 - Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid."
I can get the token, in Developer Console and Postman, but as soon as I do the API call... 401!

When I used jwt.ms to check the content of the token, I noticed that the **aud** param has nothing to do with the backend Application ID.
The value in the token is "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000", whereas the backend app ID is like "16caXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXc0".

I'm running out of ideas and need the help of some Azure gurus out there!
Help would be very much appreciated...

Here below the inbound policy as per the MS doc:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
            <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_AD_TENANT_ID/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
            <required-claims>
                <claim name="aud">
                    <value>MY8BACKEND_APP_ID_GUID</value>
                </claim>
            </required-claims>
        </validate-jwt>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <forward-request />
    </backend>
    <outbound />
    <on-error />
</policies>
```

[Screen cap of the Postman screen where I get the token (this works, but then when I send the request --> 401)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQWhU.jpg)

[Screen cap of aud param in jwt.ms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFmxc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some problems with validating Azure AD tokens a couple of years back - see my [write up](https://authguidance.com/azure-ad-troubleshooting/).

I suspect the problem is the nonce in the JWT header.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for your write up, it definitely put me on the right track.
As you explain in it, "If there is a nonce field in the JWT’s header then it is intended only for Microsoft developed Azure APIs . These tokens require special handling and will always fail standards based validation." --> that is the case.
Unfortunately, I plan to expose Logic Apps through APIM, so adding home made code to validate the jwt is not an option.

Comment: Maybe it is because I've started a few weeks ago on APIM/Functions/Logic Apps, but there is actually something I don't get here: MS is providing jwt tokens that can't be validated by its own inbound policies (validate-jwt)? how come? 

Note: another interesting thing is that when I use Postman from which I get the jwt token, I use the scope "user.read" (the one I created), and in the jwt, the scope is "User.Read profile openid email"

Comment: If I remember rightly, a couple of years back I stopped using the v2 OAuth endpoints and used v1 endpoints - in order to get rid of nonce from the JWT header so that I could validate tokens. I was not using graph API and just trying to use a custom API as in your case.

Comment: I agree with your frustration. It would be much easier if Microsoft just followed OAuth 2.0 and Open Id Connect standards by default. Instead their unnatural vendor extensions makes their tech difficult to use for common use cases. Looks like lots of people are struggling with this: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/815

Comment: Thank you so much Gary!! By using the v1 endpoints, no more nonce and it worked right away, both in Postman and Developer Console!

Comment: I just want to say thanks to Gary as well....switching everything to V1 made it work!

Comment: Thanks @GaryArcher As you noticed when it change to v1 for OAuth on authorization endpoint and token endpoint of Auth Server configuration of APIM instead of using v2 It works.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link provided by @Gary Archer is broken. Any other references please?

Comment: I fixed the link Johney

Comment: Would it work if you assign the SPA an app role to the API instead of a scope? Seems to make more sense to set it up as an app role w/application permissions since this isn't meant to be a delegated permission that the user consents to.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really required to check value of aud parameter. You could remove `required-claims` alltogether, this way token presence and signature would still be validated. If you want to make sure that token was issued for your app, just find the claim that contains app id and use it in name="..." to match against your app id value.

Comment: Hi Vitaliy, thank you for your idea. I tried what you proposed, but no luck: I removed the check on aud, but I still have the "401 - Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.".
So I guess my problem is somewhere else, and I can't find it (in the Developer Portal I can't see debug info, nor in the Activity log : it shows the "Get Token" and "Get SSO Token" calls, and they succeed).

Comment: Use test console in Azure Portal to make a call: open APIM service, go to APIs, select API, select Operation, go to Test tab. Make sure to add your token to request. This way you will get trace of the call with explanation what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you Vitaliy, I tried that and fetched the ocp-apim-trace-location, that showed an interesting piece:
        "on-error": [
            {
                "source": "validate-jwt",
                "data": {
                    "message": "JWT Validation Failed: IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey , KeyId: piVlloQDSMKxh1m2ygqGSVdgFpA\r\n'. \nkid: 'piVlloQDSMKxh1m2ygqGSVdgFpA'. \nExceptions caught:\n ''.\ntoken: '{\"typ\":\"JWT\",\"nonce\":\"Tuh4aIzD0u0CKgZg1\",\"alg\":\"RS256\",
                }
            }
        ],

Comment: Hi Vitaliy, thanks for your help: Gary pointed me in the right direction (comments in the previous answer) --> by using the v1 endpoints instead of v2, the nonce disappeared in the jwt, and it worked right away both in Developer Console and in Postman.

Comment: Hi Laurent - just to get back to you on this, I recently updated my [Azure Code Sample + Docs](https://authguidance.com/2017/11/30/azure-active-directory-setup) to use 2.0 endpoints. It is pretty unintuitive, but I got it working. Just thought I'd post back in case it's useful to you in future. Regards ..

Answer (score 0):

if using v2 version endpoint, go to -> azure ad -> app registration -> select backend-app -> manifest -> update property "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,"